# "checked" and "selected" in HTML for input do not work with AngularJS

Tags: html, angularjs, input, radio-button

I am learning AngularJS and user input. In my code, I tried to set default state for drop down menu and radio button with "selected" and "checked".

However, they do not work together with "ng-model" attribute.

Also, for the first radio button (ascending), the empty value attribute seems to hinder with "checked" attribute.

Could anyone explain why this happens and how to bypass this problem?

```
<div class="search">
<h1>Artist Directory</h1>

  <label> Search: </label>
      <input ng-model="query" placeholder="Search for artists" autofocus> 
  <label class="formgroup">by: 
      <select ng-model="listOrder" name="direction">
          <option  value ="name" selected="selected"> Name</option>
          <option value="reknown"> Reknown</option>
      </select>
  </label>

  <label class="formgroup">
         <input ng-model="direction" type="radio" value=" " checked>   Ascending
   </label>

  <label class="formgroup">
        <input ng-model="direction" type="radio" value="reverse"> Descending
  </label>

</div>
```

Comment: please provide a fiddle. this will help us helping you :)

Answer (score 0):

tie your button and select to an ng-model. Default values are the values you put in the model when the scope is first created. Then values are updated when user clicks :

```js
function test($scope) {
  $scope.selected = ['1','3'];
  $scope.checked = "green";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.1/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app>
  <h2>Todo</h2>
  <div ng-controller="test">
            <select name="" ng-model="selected" multiple>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
        </select>
      <br><br>
      <input type="radio" ng-model="checked" value="red">  Red <br/>    
      <input type="radio" ng-model="checked" value="green"> Green <br/>
      <input type="radio" ng-model="checked" value="blue"> Blue <br/>
         
         
        <br>
        Selected : {{selected}}
        <br>
        Checked : {{checked}}
  </div>
</div>
```

See it in action : **http://jsfiddle.net/913n30zf/**

Answer (score 0):

Select in AngularJS looks likes this:

```
<select ng-model="selectedOpt"
      ng-options="opt for opt in listOrder">
</select>
```

And back in the controller you set

```
$scope.selectedOpt = $scope.listOrder[0];
```

which option you want to be select by default.